# Bind DependencyProperty to Property in another class

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

In my MainWindow.xaml, I have added my UserControl to the Window. There is also a button that toggles a Boolean value call IsVisible from True/False.

In my MainUserControl.xaml, I have my datagrid(not MS grid) where its tempate points to a Control Template set in the App.xaml. This is where my IsVisible property exists.

In my App.xaml, I have a ControlTemplate which has my datagrid. If I want to bind the Visible property of my Column to the IsVisible property in the MainUserControl class.

I'm having trouble binding the property. I've tried using TemplateBinding, but that can't work since the the TemplatedParent is not the UserControl. I've tried using RelativeSource and setting the Ancestor, but that didn't work either. Does anyone have any advice to help me out?

EDIT:
this is the code in my ControlTemplate

```
<Column FieldName="Column1" 
             Title="Column1" 
             Visible="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}, AncestorLevel=2}, Path=IsVisible}"  />
```

Comment: Why don't you post the relevant XAML parts? That would help a lot to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the fact you are setting `AncestorLevel=2`, try removing that and it should work for you.

`AncestorLevel=2` would only allow this to work if you had to `UserControl1`s, one inside the other as it says bind to the second instance of `local:UserControl1` encountered when traversing up.

Comment: I removed the AncestorLevel=2 and I still got the same binding error:

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Project1.UserControl1', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=IsVisible; DataItem=null; target element is 'Column' (HashCode=8963119); target property is 'Visible' (type 'Boolean')

Comment: I re-tweaked it thanks to you.. disregard my previous comments! Thanks